# title on the list activity

Tags: android

my question is how i can add a title on ListActivity

I used the following code

```
final boolean customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
                          if ( customTitleSupported )
                          {
                              getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
                          }
                          final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitle);
                          if ( myTitleText != null )
                          {
                              myTitleText.setText("Select Service Provider");
                          }
```

But it not works on ListActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing else works, you can extend Activity instead of ListActivity, and in your layout you can place a ListView that you bind your data to.

Comment: how i can add a ListView in Activity

Comment: Reply how i can i add a ListView in Activity

Comment: I'm assuming you've got some experience with creating an Activity, and in that you should have experience working with the layout of that activity (often called main.xml). A ListView is a view that you can include within your main.xml (or any other layout). Once your ListView is available you need to configure it for your purpose -- something that ListActivity already does for you. From here, you might want to start by examining the ListActivity source code; you can find that at [http://netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java].